# Add Appended Data and Remove Selected Data

Tags: jquery

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Y9K8p/1/

[image]

I'm working on a basic website designer for my tablet. It works by mirroring the html and css to a textarea for easy preview and saving.

To add an element all the user needs to do to is type it out in the textbox and if it has a class they can add that as well. Which will append as either `<header></header>` without a class or `<header class="head"></header>` with a class.

The body is not to be removed, but whatever else the user adds can. So if I click or touch the input with the value header and click remove. I don't want to remove all headers just the one that's appended first into the body as seen in the screenshot.

I'm not sure how to go about this, hence why I'm asking, "How can this be accomplished?".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm getting ready to head to work so won't be able to review this post until 5pm tonight. I made a simple fiddle that kind of shows what I'm trying to do.

Here's that code:

```
var counter = 2;

$(".add-html-class").click(function () {
    $(".html-elms").append('<input type="text" id="text' + counter + '" value="<'+ $(".html-elm").val() +' class="'+ $(".html-elm-class").val() +'">" disabled="true">');
    counter++;
})

$(".del-html-class").click(function () {
    if (counter == 2) {
        alert("No more textbox to remove");
        return false;
    }
    counter--;

    $(".html-elms #text" + counter).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9K8p/12/)

But One thing which is i am not clear from your question that if you wanted to remove element which is added first you have to search it then remove it. Put all in array then put it in for loop then remove it. This is optional if u want it do. Otherwise look fiddle which is working fine adding textboxes and removing also.

```
$(".add-html-class").click(function () {
   $(".html-elms").append('<input type="text" id="text' + counter + '" value="'+ $(".html-elm").val() +'" class="'+ $(".html-elm-class").val() +'">');
   counter++;
})
```

And i like your project idea. very Nice. I think its HTML creator is what your making right?.

Comment: It's suppose to display as a layer type system without incorporating the elements containers. It's a website designer for Android and Linux. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have extra < > 's in your append code that is splitting elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/Y9K8p/13/

```
 $(".html-elms").append('<input type="text" id="text' + counter + '"
   value="'+ $(".html-     elm").val() +'"  
  class="'+ $(".html-elm-class").val() +'" disabled="true">');
```

Comment: actually reading back your question after im wondering if you wanted to split the element..